sudoers for passwordless sudoedit, except for sudoers
I want to configure passwordless sudoedit, to edit files under /etc with the exception of sudoers files themselves.
I tried using the following /etc/sudoers.d/sudoedit:
%sudo ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: sudoedit ^/etc/(?!sudo).*$

but that does not seem to work as sudo uses an old regex engine without the negative lookahead feature.
Is there another way to achieve this? Maybe with the combination of /etc and the negation of !/etc/sudo?

I'm not a sudo expert, but you might be able to take advantage that later patterns have priority, and so use
%sudo ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: sudoedit ^/etc/[a-zA-Z0-9._/-]+$, \
 !sudoedit /etc/*sudo*, \
 !sudoedit /etc/*..*

The regexp tries to include all reasonable paths under /etc, which includes files with . and _ and so on. The next line forbids sudo from appearing, to avoid  /etc/./sudoers. The last line forbids .., which avoids /etc/../. There may still be some exceptional files that are not allowed but should be, for example systemd has files with \x2d in the filename, and there may be filenames containing sudo which are not within /etc/sudoers.d/.

It's hard to get negatives working usefully; there are often way too many loopholes - and you only need one

I tried many combinations of regular non-regex globs, but could not get a satisfactory result. I ended up with a positive and a negative regex, but to be honest, now I am not sure I will move forward with this, as I cannot be sure this won't leave any loopholes....  https://regex101.com/r/PlBWkP/1
%sudo ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: sudoedit ^/etc/\S+$, !sudoedit ^/etc/(.+|sudo).*$
